# How is a set an event

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For problems where sets are described as events such as:

> In a group of 12 friends, 8 study French, 4 study french only and 2 study neither French nor Cantonese.  Let A be the event 'studies French' and let B be the event 'studies Cantonese'.

To my mind, A and B are sets and the elements are people (friends).  How are they then also events?  Is it because the 12 friends comprise the "sample space" and the event is "sampling"?

A set is any collection of objects (mathematical or not).  An event is "an outcome or defined collection of outcomes of a random experiment" (well, according to Statistics.com).  I don't think it's a contentious subject so I'll quote wikipedia here for the definition of an event: "In probability theory, an event is a set of outcomes of an experiment (a subset of the sample space) to which a probability is assigned."

Where is the experiment in the initial statements?  Or am I confusing the sets defined by the text with my own e.g.

Set A={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
Set B={e,f,g,h,i,j}
compliment of the sets = {k,l}

Perhaps the categories are the 'elements' of the sets in this instance?
Set A={any friend who studies French}
Set B={any friend who studies Cantonese}
compliment of the sets = {any friend who studies neither}

I am new to this but I've heard of set builder notation.  I'm wondering how to describe "Let A be the event 'studies French' and let B be the event 'studies Cantonese'." in set builder in that case.

Comment: Events are sets in probability that contain outcomes. That's just the language we use.

Comment: Yes… I see.  I think the text I am working out of, usually it is very good, but in this case they are using contracted expressions, wherein “Let event A=studies Mandarin” should be written “let Event A=a randomly selected friend studies Mandarin”

Comment: I’ve come to the conclusion that this passage in the text may simply be poorly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > In a group of 12 friends, 8 study French, 4 study French only and 2 study neither French nor Cantonese.  Let A be the event 'studies
> > French' and let B be the event 'studies Cantonese'.
>
> To my mind, A and B are sets and the elements are people (friends).
> How are they then also events?  Is it because the event is "sampling"?
>
> I'm wondering how to describe "Let A be the event 'studies French' in set builder notation

How an event is defined depends on how the experiment is set up. (Click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4311563/21813) for my detailed explanation.)

It appears that in this experiment, $A$ is **the event that the chosen friend studies French**, and equals $$\{x\mid x\text{ studies French}\}$$ (equivalently, list those four friends within the braces).

In a different experiment, {Jill-Bill, Jill-Phil} might be the event of both chosen friends studying French. Notice that each outcome in this experiment comprises two names; this is because, unlike the above single-trial experiment, this experiment has two trials.

> Set A={any friend who studies French}

If you'd like to describe the set (in lieu of either option above), replace “any friend who” with “all friends who”, and omit that pair of braces.

> "An event is an outcome or defined collection of outcomes of a random experiment"
> (well, according to Statistics.com).

We usually abuse notation, writing $P(HTT)$ and $P(HTT,THT,TTH)$ instead of $P(\{HTT\})$ and $P(\{HTT,THT,TTH\}).$ But, technically, an elementary event (an event with a single element) is still a *set*, rather than an outcome.

> I'll quote wikipedia:
> "an event is a  a subset of the sample space"

Yes, exactly. And the sample space varies with the experiment.